# Firefox Add-on: Get the item id of an existing bookmark folder by foldername

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I'm trying to make my add-on save bookmarks in it's own bookmark folder.

This function created the desired folder, but I want it to return the id of the existing folder instead of forever making millions of new ones if it can find it by name:

```
function special_bookmark_folder()
{
  menuFolder = bmsvc_service().bookmarksMenuFolder;

  // <Try and find the bookmark folder here!>

  return bmsvc_service().createFolder(menuFolder, ":: Bookmarkr ::", bmsvc_service().DEFAULT_INDEX);
  // else return id of existing folder if it's found here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the [Places query APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Querying_Places), which isn't the most straightforward task. Thankfully there is [an example with exactly what you want](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/services/sync/tps/extensions/tps/modules/bookmarks.jsm#201)